# How to read formData field from http-request in node.js?

Tags: node.js, form-data

I have method that upload files to nodeJS. But now, I want to send the files and another data:

```
 formData.append('files[]', files[i], filename); --> OK
```

Now, I add this:

```
formData.append('ORIGIN', origin_array);
```

I send data like this:

```
this.http.post(url, formData, options).pipe(map(result => result))
```

In nodeJS, I am using "multer" library for get files, and it is OK, but I don't know how to get origin item.

In node, I have this code:

```
module.exports = {
uploadMultimedia: multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fieldNameSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        fileSize: 1000 * 1024 * 1024 // 5000MB
    }
}).single('file'),
uploadMultimediaArray: multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fieldNameSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        fileSize: 1000 * 1024 * 1024 // 5000MB
    }
}).array('files[]', 10)
```

}

And this is my API who calls multer:

```
exports.multimedia = function (req, res) {
  //CODE
 }
```

Sorry about my english.

Comment: Can you post how the code on your node server looks like when you get the post request? I am guessing you can access the `ORIGIN` by doing something like this: `request.getParameter("ORIGIN");`

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: @John 1 - req.getParameter returns "req.getParameter is not a function"
2- My body is empty :(

Comment: I do not know the exact syntax, but have a look at the answer I linked to. Maybe it can be of help

Comment: But I send a FormData not a form